# TestNG - configfailurepolicy="continue" is not working for retried test

Tags: java, testng, testng.xml

Though configfailurepolicy value is set as "continue", the retried test is getting skipped.

**Example:**

testng.xml - At suite level, configfailurepolicy value is set as "continue"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="1"
    configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <test name="Front-End">
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.tests.ExcepionAfterMethodTest">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Test: Throwing an exception in configuration (i.e., @AfterMethod) method to cause failure. And using RetryAnalyzer to retry the failed test.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ExcepionAfterMethodTest{

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("Before Method");
    }
    
    @Test (alwaysRun=true, retryAnalyzer=RetryAnalyzer.class)
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Method");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test (alwaysRun=true)
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method1");
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void afterMethod() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After Method");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

RetryAnalyzer: Will retry once, if a failure occurs.

```
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int counter = 0;
    private int retryLimit = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (counter < retryLimit) {
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Result: Because of failure in @AfterMethod, the test is retried, but the @Test  is skipped. Hence, 'Method' is not printed in the result at the 5th line.

> Before Method
>
> Method
>
> After Method
>
> Before Method
>
> After Method
>
> Method1
>
> After Method

Expected Result: As configfailurepolicy is configured as "continue", the retried test shouldn't be skipped. So, expecting 'Method' should be printed in the result at the 5th line as below.

> Before Method
>
> Method
>
> After Method
>
> Before Method
>
> **Method**
>
> After Method
>
> Method1
>
> After Method

Comment: Raised a ticket at github.
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2148

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed with 7.1.0 version of TestNG.

Ref: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2148